# Importing css file in react on a event

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to import a css file on some condition to a react component. And if the condition changes it should change the css file. It is getting the Lighttheme css file and render it. On the event it changed to Darktheme file. But if the event occurs once again it doesn't go to the LightTheme file. This is the function

```
const LightTheme = React.lazy(() => import('./style1'));
const DarkTheme = React.lazy(() => import('./style2'));

const ThemeSelector = ({ color }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <React.Suspense fallback={<></>}>
                {(color === "DarkTheme") && <LightTheme />}
                {(color === "LightTheme") && <DarkTheme />}
            </React.Suspense>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with dynamically importing CSS files but if you were to do it in a class based component, you should perform a conditional check in componentWillMount() method and use require('filename.css'). This might work in Dev but to make it work in production you might have to configure webpack accordingly. A better solution would be to use a single CSS file. Use the class .light and .dark with your custom CSS classes and in your component assign the classes based on your condition.

className = {color === 'DarkTheme'? ('your-custom-class-dark') : ('your-custom-class-light')}

Comment: But if i had more theme then the size of the file increases. And the ternary operator also can't be used??